# Why are my AppBarButton(s) inheriting margin from a TextBlock style?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I am working on a Windows 8 store desktop application and I am getting a weird issue with my AppBarButton(s) inside the BottomAppBar.

This is the code for my BottomAppBar just to show that nothing is being set in the xaml there:

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Background="SlateGray">
            <AppBarButton Label="UseGPS"
                          Icon="Target"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Reset"
                          Icon="Clear"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Save to File"
                          Icon="Save" />
            <AppBarSeparator />
            <AppBarButton Label="Copy Longitude"
                          Icon="Copy"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Copy Latitude"
                          Icon="Copy" />
        </CommandBar>
    </Page.BottomAppBar>
```

The real issue lies in this xaml code inside my Generic.Xaml resource dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" 
                Value="Segoe UI" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" 
                Value="26" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" 
                Value="{StaticResource ApplicationForegroundThemeBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Margin"
                Value="10,0" />
    </Style>
```

Specifically this line : `<Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0" />`

With this code in place the Buttons' icons get clipped:

[image: Clipped Icons]

When that line is commented out I get normal looking icons like this:

[image: Non Clipped Icons]

I have tried setting `Style={x:Null}` for both CommandBar and AppBarButton, I have tried setting `Margin=0` for both as well but neither solved the issue. I don't understand why the style targeting TextBlock is causing the icons to clip in the AppBarButton. I can't just comment out the setter for the style since it is actually needed by TextBlocks so if anyone has a solution that doesn't involve removing that setter I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are your icons from a font?

Comment: @ChrisW. my icons are the built in icons xaml provides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason is, because the icon's are actually just [glyph's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn252842) from the [SymbolIcon class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbolicon) that uses the Segoe MDL2 Assets **font** and render as **TextBlock** at runtime. Hence the inheritance from the TargetType.

You could easily just shut out that inheritance at the instance like;

```
<CommandBar Background="SlateGray">
   <CommandBar.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
         <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
      </Style>
   </CommandBar.Resources>
            <AppBarButton Label="UseGPS"
                          Icon="Target"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Reset"
                          Icon="Clear"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Save to File"
                          Icon="Save" />
            <AppBarSeparator />
            <AppBarButton Label="Copy Longitude"
                          Icon="Copy"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Copy Latitude"
                          Icon="Copy" />
</CommandBar>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Your fix worked perfectly and you also explained why it was happening, thanks man!

Comment: @GordonAllocman Hey I learned something from one of your answers just the other day, so it's just reciprocal. :)